# Cannot run remote script via bash script but can through terminal

Tags: bash, centos, scripting

`ssh -p 60022 centos@localhost 'bash -s '< ./update.sh`

If I run the following command through the terminal, all works fine and `update.sh` is ran on the remote machine.

If I place the same command into a bash script, `deploy.sh` for example, then execute with

```
. ./deploy.sh
```

from the same directory, it will not allow me to execute the script with the error:

`: No such file or directory`

I'm assuming this is something to do with working directories or something similar, but I can't find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was line endings, when executing the file remotely with windows line endings nothing would work.

Changing the line endings to UNIX fixed this for me.